# Problems with cookies in PHP not unsetting across all domains

Tags: php, cookies, setcookie

I'm having some problems with Cookies is PHP. On Localhost, cookies don't seem to be deleting and users remain logged in via WWW.somesite.com but the logout works on SOMESITE.com.

This is the code that deals with the cookies being set/unset:

```
public static function cookie($name, $value){

    $host = apache_request_headers();

    $host = $host['Host'];

    $host = explode('.', $host);

    $count = count($host);

    if($count >= 2) {
        $host = ($host[0] == 'test') ? 'test.' . $host[$count - 2] . "." . $host[$count - 1] : $host[$count - 2] . "." . $host[$count - 1];
    } else {
        $host = $host[0];
    }

    //$host = explode(':', $host);
    //$host = $host[0];

    //Core::prnt($host);

    if($value === NULL) {

        setcookie($name, $value, time() - Options::getSetting('U_SESSION_TIMEOUT'), '/', $host);

        Core::prnt($_COOKIE);

        return;

    }

    setcookie($name, $value, time() + Options::getSetting('U_SESSION_TIMEOUT'), '/', $host);

}
```

Any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong would be extremely helpful.

Comment: Make sure you have the same calculation for `$host` in this function and wherever you're erasing the cookies.  If you want cookies to be shared between `server.com` and `www.server.com`, make sure `$host` starts with a `.`, e.g. `.server.com`

Comment: If you make this an answer I'll accept it. It seems it's the `.`'s fault.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have the same calculation for $host in this function and wherever you're erasing the cookies.

If you want cookies to be shared between `server.com` and `www.server.com`, make sure `$host` starts with a `.`, e.g. `.server.com`